# Struggling to get Selenium to finish automatic checkout

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I've been playing around with Selenium and have been trying to get my automated checkout working. So far it's been pretty successful, but I've hit a snag and can't seem the end part of my code working. I've tried arranging my 'sleeps' and 'implicit_waits' in every way I can think of but to no success. I keep getting thrown "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="creditCardNumber"]" If someone can help me get this going I would really appreciate it!

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = Firefox()
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)


def get_nike():

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('https://www.nike.com/')

    men_shoes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a')
    action.move_to_element(men_shoes)
    action.perform()

    new_releases = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]')
    avoid_wrong_selection = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div[2]/a[2]')
    action.move_to_element(avoid_wrong_selection)
    action.move_to_element(new_releases)
    action.perform()
    new_releases.click()  # you have to click the element itself

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    selected_shoes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Wall"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/main/section/div/div[12]/div/figure/a[2]/div/div/img') #can also use linked text
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", selected_shoes) # scrolls to shoes
    selected_shoes.click()

    get_size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/form/div[1]/fieldset/div/div[10]/label')
    action.move_to_element(get_size)  # selects size
    get_size.click()

    time.sleep(1)

    add_bag = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div') #requires web element
    action.move_to_element(add_bag) # adds item to bag
    add_bag.click() 

    to_checkout = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button[2]')
    action.move_to_element(to_checkout) # brings you to cart
    to_checkout.click()

    first_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="firstName"]')
    first_name.send_keys("Bingo")

    last_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lastName"]')
    last_name.send_keys("Bongo")

    transition_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-address-input"]')
    transition_address.send_keys('1453 E curfluffle street')

    manual_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a')
    manual_address.click()

    real_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="address1"]') # types address
    real_address.send_keys('53 sterling street')

    city = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="city"]') # types city
    city.send_keys('pittsburgh')

    state_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="state"]')
    selections = Select(state_dropdown) # selects state from the dropdown
    
    selections.select_by_value("PA")

    zip_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="postalCode"]')
    zip_code.send_keys('15203') #sends zip code

    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
    email.send_keys('gythfnjgfvn@gmail.com')

    phone_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phoneNumber"]')
    phone_number.send_keys('456-906-2354')

    save_and_continue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div/div[2]/button')
    action.move_to_element(save_and_continue)
    save_and_continue.click()

    time.sleep(1)

    continue_to_payment = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[2]/div/div[3]/div/button')
    action.move_to_element(continue_to_payment)
    continue_to_payment.click()

    
    cc_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="creditCardNumber"]')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    #scroll down to card info and enter card info
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", cc_number)
    time.sleep(2)
    cc_number.send_keys('123456789101112')

get_nike()
```

The problem in particular the end.

```
    continue_to_payment = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[2]/div/div[3]/div/button')
    action.move_to_element(continue_to_payment)
    continue_to_payment.click()

    
    cc_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="creditCardNumber"]')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    #scroll down to card info and enter card info
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", cc_number)
    time.sleep(2)
    cc_number.send_keys('123456789101112')
```

Comment: Can you post the html of the element in question. Also check if it is in any iframes.

Comment: Heres the innerhtml, is this what you mean?  <input maxlength="20" class="mod-ncss-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm" id="creditCardNumber" onautocomplete="off" value="" type="tel" tabindex="0" data-shortname="cc">

Comment: If it moves to another page add some wait prior to finding the element. <iframe> check if its in one of these and driver switch to it

Comment: The only thing is it doesn't move to another page. It just opens the bottom of the page up, where I would then have to scroll down and enter credit card info. This the part that keeps messing up as I can't get the page to move down and locate the credit card input

Answer (score 1):

Just use webdriver wait to wait for the element to pop up and send keys.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "creditCardNumber"))).send_keys("123456789101112")
```

Fixing other code to make it more stable.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
def get_nike():

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('https://www.nike.com/')

    men_shoes = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='Men']")))
    action.move_to_element(men_shoes).perform()

    new_releases = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@role='menuitem' and text()='New Releases']")
    action.move_to_element(new_releases).click().perform()

    selected_shoes = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='Nike ZoomX Invincible Run Flyknit']//img")))
    selected_shoes.click()

    get_size = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='US 10.5']")))
    get_size.click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This answer seems closer to the one I'm looking for, but when it runs the 'wait.until' it still will not scroll down to the credit card input.

Comment: @Jamesyt60 all you'd do is just use your scroll to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to check if a WebElement is visible in viewport, do not use selenium waits, they are plenty of bugs.

```
public static Boolean isVisibleInViewport(WebElement element) {
      WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)element).getWrappedDriver();

      return (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
          "var elem = arguments[0],                 " +
          "  box = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),    " +
          "  cx = box.left + box.width / 2,         " +
          "  cy = box.top + box.height / 2,         " +
          "  e = document.elementFromPoint(cx, cy); " +
          "for (; e; e = e.parentElement) {         " +
          "  if (e === elem)                        " +
          "    return true;                         " +
          "}                                        " +
          "return false;                            "
          , element);
    }
```

Just convert the Java method to a python function and pass to it the WebElement you're looking for.